# Expected value of the absolute value of the difference of two random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, absolute-value

I have to compute the absolute value of an estimator defined as $T_5=\frac{1}{2}E[|X_1-X_2|]$ in order to state if it is unbiased for $\sigma$, where $X$ is distributed as a $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I am stuck in computing the expected value of the absolute value of the difference of two normal random variables. Any hint?

Comment: $X_1 -X_2$ has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $2\sigma^2$.  You might consider the mean of a half-normal distribution (which involves $\sqrt{\pi}$ so the answer to your question is likely to be "yes")

Comment: You're right! So maybe I can proceed in order to obtain a half-normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ in order to use the known values of the distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid random variables such that $X_1\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $X_2\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$, then
$$
X_1-X_2\sim\mathcal N(0,2\sigma^2).
$$
If $X\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $Y=|X|$ has the [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) and
$$
\operatorname EY=\frac{\sqrt2\sigma}{\sqrt\pi}.
$$
Hence, we have that
$$
\frac12\operatorname E|X_1-X_2|=\frac12\frac{\sqrt2\sqrt2\sigma}{\sqrt\pi}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt\pi}.
$$